# Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" in AWS SNS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-sdk

I want to send SMS via AWS SNS service. For that I've wrote code like below in AppDelegate.

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                          initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSWest2
                                                          identityPoolId:@"us-west-2:xxxx"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Here is the code for ViewController.

```
AWSSNS *awssns = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];
AWSSNSPublishInput *input = [[AWSSNSPublishInput alloc] init];
[input setMessage:@"This is test from Mrugesh"];
[input setPhoneNumber:@"+91xxxxxxxxxx"];
[awssns publish:input completionHandler:^(AWSSNSPublishResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

Everytime I get error like below.

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Please help me to solve this problem.
Answers or guidance can be can welcomed in swift / Objective - C.

Comment: Seems like a permission issue. Have you attached appropriate policies to your cognito role?

Comment: Where it is located??

Comment: in the IAM console